# enable AMD-v on Asus M4A88T-M with AMD Phenom II X6 1090T

Tags: vmware, virtualization, amd-phenom

I've problems with x64-virtualisation in VMware Workstation.
I don't know what's the problem:

Hardware: AMD Phenom II 1090T (does support AMD-v), ASUS M4A88T-M Mainboard and 8GB of RAM.
That should be enough to do some little virtualisation.

Software: Windows 7 Enterprise x64, VMware Workstation 7.1, ESX 4.1 as VM in VMware Workstation

I tried to create a VM on that ESX but got this error:
[image]

I looked in my BIOS but found nothing like "enable virtualization". The Mainboard manual doesn't have information about virtualization.

I hope someone can tell me what to do to allow x64-guests on my esx-vm.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [this](http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?board_id=1&model=M4A77TD%20PRO&id=20091104070321500&page=1&SLanguage=en-us) ASUS calls the setting "Secure Virtual Machine Mode" in the BIOS.  According to your [manual](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM3/M4A88TM_LE/#download), it should be listed under Advanced / CPU Configuration. There is a German manual on the ASUS site if your BIOS uses that.  The German manual calls it "Secure Virtual Machine Modus" or "SVM".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This option is already enabled in my bios...

Comment: Don't know then.  Perhaps VMware hasn't added support for your processor?  I know the 1090T is brand new.  Does Virtual PC or VirtualBox allow you to enable hardware virtualization?  Does the [MS tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ee2a17f-8538-4619-8d1c-05d27e11adb2) show you have the capability?

Comment: Microsofts Tool says that my computer is configured with hardware-assisted virtualization. That means, VMware Workstation is eventually missconfigured...

Comment: I found the reason why this is not working: http://communities.vmware.com/message/1455752 - VMware has to develop VT-x/AMD-v path through first to get x64 nested VMs working. Thanks for your help Bacon.

Comment: Yup, thanks, this appeared at the top of a Google search and resolved our confusion about why there was _ostensibly_ no reference to AMD-V in the firmware menu.