# How to enable hardware virtualization on AMD Asus motherboard

Tags: bios, virtualization

I have an Asus M5A97 R2.0 motherboard, and an AMD fx-4350 processor. I know you have to go into bios to enable virtualization technology, but i can't find it anywhere. Online it says this processor can support it.  Any other examples i've seen from this page only work for intel.

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:windows-xp-mode], a [later update](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/why-am-i-receiving-errors-about-hav) removes the requirement for hardware virtualization.

Comment: Did ASUS stop providing documentation for it's products? Oh wait, no it didn't. Thanks, Google! - http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A97_R20/HelpDesk_Manual

Answer (score 51):

Enter your firmware setup, set it to Advanced Mode if you haven’t done so already.

The setting is located at: Advanced → CPU Configuration → SVM

Upon saving, the PC *may* turn off completely and turn back on again, if I remember correctly. This is normal.

This information is, naturally, available in your board’s [manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM3+/M5A97_R2.0/E8046_M5A97_R2.pdf), page 3-15. ;)

Comment: @user325622: Please select this as the correct answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: SVM is a.k.a. AMD-V, as described here: http://superuser.com/questions/272590/enable-amd-v-on-asus-m4a88t-m-with-amd-phenom-ii-x6-1090t

Comment: For me it was just called "Intel Virtualization"

Comment: I have tried to follow the steps, but this is what it appears in my advanced tab of the bios https://imgur.com/M4sa027 - Asus VivoBook X505Z

Comment: The full question can be found here https://superuser.com/questions/1497988/unable-to-correctly-activate-or-use-virtualization-on-asus-vivobook-x505za-with

Comment: Called Intel Virtualization for me on an ASUS mobo, also had a "VMX" labels, description mentioned "Vanderpool Technologies", just an FYI since mine used a different label :)