# Can't enable CPU Virtualization or SVM on ASUS M5A97 motherboard and AMD FX-8320E CPU

Tags: cpu, motherboard, virtualization

I can't seem to get CPU virtualization enabled for my PC.  I've searched other threads and they each seem to point to a setting in Advanced  -> CPU Configuration but I see no setting to enable virtualization or SVM.

Motherboard is ASUS M5A97 Revision 1.02 and CPU is AMD FX-8320E.  Everything I'm reading says that this combination should allow virtualization.

Here are the options that are available to me in the BIOS:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlJ4W.jpg

Here is a reference thread that I've also followed but to no avail:
[How to enable hardware virtualization on AMD Asus motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/757239/how-to-enable-hardware-virtualization-on-amd-asus-motherboard)

I'm a pretty computer literate person and I have virtualization enabled on another PC.  I just can't seem to get this one working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I've seen that post as well.  Of course, right after I posted this I tried a solution and it worked.  I will put an answer.  Very frustrating...

Answer (score 1):

So right after I posted this I went to the same page and loaded the "Optimized Defaults".  Several options appeared in the advanced menu, including SVM, which is enabled by default.  I don't recall making any custom settings in the BIOS previously, but this seems to have solved the problem.  Thanks!