# Unable to correctly activate or use virtualization on Asus Vivobook X505ZA with Ryzen 5 2500U CPU for Android Studio

Tags: cpu, bios, android

I need to enable hardware virtualization on Asus Vivobook X505ZA with Ryzen 5 2500U CPU in order to have Android Studio 3.5.1 run Virtual devices.

I have tried this...

[How to enable hardware virtualization on AMD Asus motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/757239/how-to-enable-hardware-virtualization-on-amd-asus-motherboard)

...but the option mentioned in the answer does not appear
[image: Asus Bios Without SVM AMD-V option]

I have also checked that the bios is up to date, and I have the same last 
version 311
https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-15-X505ZA/HelpDesk_BIOS/

The support for virtualization over AMD in Android Studio is mentioned here https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/07/09/android-studio-device-emulator-now-works-amd-processors-hyper-v/

And even when in the Bios is the setting is not shown, it seems that virtualization is already working

[image]

But when I try to create a new Android Virtual Device the error still appears
[image]

It seems to me that I might be missing something very obvious

Comment: If Windows says it’s enabled, it is. However, it may be in use. Do you perhaps have conflicting virtualization software (like Hyper-V) installed?

Comment: I have just checked - Hyper-V is not enabled/installed in my Windows 10

Comment: @Moab did you check the provided link in the question ? - https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/07/09/android-studio-device-emulator-now-works-amd-processors-hyper-v/

Comment: Amd has their own virtualization technology (AMDV and AMDV-i) and its not compatible with earlier versions of AS (You must use Android Studio 3.2 Beta or higher)

Comment: Thanks for your comments I have just read again the article from AndroidPolice and the missing step was to Enable "Hyper-V" manually. - my Android Studio is 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

After reading some comments I have just found the missing step

```
you might have to enable Hyper-V manually
```

[image]

That was mentioned in the same article I provided in the question

https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/07/09/android-studio-device-emulator-now-works-amd-processors-hyper-v/

> To use the new emulator on AMD processors, you'll need Android Studio
>   3.2 Beta or higher, along with v27.3.8 of the emulator (available through the Studio SDK Manager). Windows 10 with the April 2018 update
>   is also required, and you might have to enable Hyper-V manually.

After **restarting windows to finish Hyper-V installation** this is how a Pixel 2 emulator looks on a AMD procesor with Android Studio 3.5.1

[image]